# Add NA as a factor level for the whole Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset, where one of my tables has columns which are completely factors. The only data in them is either 'yes' or a NA value.Every column has only one factor level, which is yes. I want to make the NA a factor level too. Unfortunately my understanding of the addNA() function is quite poor. Please could someone help me add the NA as a factor level to the entire dataset in a more concise way, than me having to type it out individually for each column. Thank you

```
xl<- structure(list(G = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "yes", class = "factor"), A = structure(c(1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), .Label = "yes", class = "factor"), 
L = structure(c(2L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
NA, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
P = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = "yes", class = "factor"), 
C = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = "yes", class = "factor"), 
S = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA), .Label = "yes", class = "factor"), M = structure(c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "yes", class = "factor"), 
F = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = "yes", class = "factor")), .Names =    c("G", "A", "L", "P", "C", "S", "M", "F"), row.names = c("row_1", "row_2", "row_3", "row_4", "row_5", "row_6", "row_7", "row_8", "row_10", "row_11"), class = "data.frame")
xl <- addNA(xl)
```

Comment: You need to apply `addNA` to the columns, not the entire data.frame. Try `xl[] <- lapply(xl, addNA)` Or with `dplyr`, `xl %>% mutate_all(addNA)`

Comment: @MrFlick Ahhh, thank you!!! I tried doing xl[,1:8] <- apply(xl, addNA) and it didn't work for me, and it didn't occur for me to try the xl[]. Thank you so much!!

Comment: It is not `apply` but rather `lapply` look again at the code given..

Comment: @Onyambu autocorrect corrected my lapply to apply in the previous answer, but on R I was typing in lapply. Thanks for the catch though.

Answer (score 2):

`purrr` came to save you:

```
library(tidyverse)

xl_new <- xl %>% 
  map_df(factor, levels = c("yes", "NA"))
```

or alternative using `forcats` as well:

```
xl_new <- xl %>% 
  map_df(fct_explicit_na, "NA")
```

Answer (score 2):

Branching off of @FMM's use of `forcats::fct_explicit_na`, which I really like, you can use `dplyr::mutate_all` since these columns are all factors. If you had different types of columns but wanted to do this for just the factor ones, you could instead use `dplyr::mutate_if` with `is.factor` as a predicate.

```r
library(tidyverse)

xl %>%
  mutate_all(fct_explicit_na, "NA")
#>      G   A   L  P  C   S   M  F
#> 1  yes yes yes NA NA  NA  NA NA
#> 2   NA yes yes NA NA  NA  NA NA
#> 3   NA  NA  NA NA NA  NA yes NA
#> 4   NA  NA  NA NA NA  NA  NA NA
#> 5   NA  NA yes NA NA  NA  NA NA
#> 6   NA yes yes NA NA  NA  NA NA
#> 7   NA  NA yes NA NA yes yes NA
#> 8   NA  NA  NA NA NA  NA  NA NA
#> 9   NA yes yes NA NA  NA  NA NA
#> 10  NA yes yes NA NA  NA  NA NA

xl %>%
  mutate_all(fct_explicit_na, "NA") %>%
  str()
#> 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  8 variables:
#>  $ G: Factor w/ 2 levels "yes","NA": 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#>  $ A: Factor w/ 2 levels "yes","NA": 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1
#>  $ L: Factor w/ 3 levels "no","yes","NA": 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 2
#>  $ P: Factor w/ 2 levels "yes","NA": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#>  $ C: Factor w/ 2 levels "yes","NA": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#>  $ S: Factor w/ 2 levels "yes","NA": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2
#>  $ M: Factor w/ 2 levels "yes","NA": 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2
#>  $ F: Factor w/ 2 levels "yes","NA": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```